# Transposing Multiple dates by sorting min to max based on unique ID and appending to DataFrame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

Given Data is

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10/20/2019 |
| 2 | 11/02/2019 |
| 3 | 12/12/2019 |
| 1 | 02/06/2019 |
| 1 | 05/14/2018 |
| 3 | 5/13/2019 |
| 2 | 07/20/2018 |
| 3 | 08/23/2019 |
| 2 | 06/25/2018 |

I want in This format

| id | date1 | date2 | date3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 05/14/2018 | 02/06/2019 | 10/20/2019 |
| 2 | 06/25/2018 | 07/20/2018 | 11/02/2019 |
| 3 | 05/13/2019 | 08/23/2019 | 12/12/2019 |

I am using For Loop to implement this on 4,00,000+ Unique Ids and its time-consuming. Is there any easy method?

I am using this code:

Each Policy number has Multiple DATEs, I want them arranged in min to max in a row in different columns like mentioned in 2nd table.

```
f= pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0,len(uni_pol)):
    d=ct.loc[ct["Policy_no"]== uni_pol[I]]
    t=d.sort values ('DATE", ascending=True).T
    df=pd.DataFrame(t)
    a=df. loc['Policy_no' ]
    col=df.columns
    df['Policy_no']= a.loc[ col[0] ]

    for j in range(0, len(col)):
        nn= str(j+1)
        name="Paydt"+nn
        df[name] = df[col[j]]
        CC= col[j]
        df=df.drop([cc], axi5-1)
        j=j+1

    f = f.append(df. loc[' DATE'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

`sort_values` by "date"; then `groupby` "id" and create a list from dates; this builds a Series. Then create a DataFrame from the lists in the Series:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
s = df.sort_values(by='date').groupby('id')['date'].agg(list)
out = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index, columns=[f'date{i}' for i in range(1,len(s.iat[0])+1)]).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   id      date1      date2      date3
0   1 2018-05-14 2019-02-06 2019-10-20
1   2 2018-06-25 2018-07-20 2019-11-02
2   3 2019-05-13 2019-08-23 2019-12-12
```

Comment: @datamind Great. FYI, you can accept an answer if your question is resolved, by clicking on the checkmark next to it